# jquery autocomplete json response not filling up the textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting proper json response and I put javascript alert to check it, but not able to fill the data into text box using the response,why following code is not returning the items list to text box dropdown.

```
response($.map(data, function (item) {

                         alert(item.task_id);
                        // getPreventDefault();

                             return { label: item.module_task, value: item.task_id};
                   }))
```

is not working, i.e. it is not filling out the text box even though I got item.task_id and item.module_task correctly inside the success block.
**

```
enter code here


(function( $ ){
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).on('click', '.autocomplete', function(){
      $('[id^="repairRecordsTask"]').each(function() {
        $(this).autocomplete({
            minLength:3,
            open: function() {
                // After menu has been opened, set width to 100px
                $('.ui-menu')
                    .width(100);
            } ,

             source : function(request, response) {

                 //alert("inside the autocomplete ");
                $.ajax({
                  //  alert("inside ajax");
                    url : "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Task_Search_Controller.do",
                    type : "GET",
                    minLength: 3,

                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    autoFill: true,
                    //term is the input from request object
                    data : {
                       term : request.term
                    },
                    dataType : "json",

                    success : function(data) {
                               alert(data.toString());
                     response($.map(data, function (item) {

                         alert(item.task_id);
                        // getPreventDefault();

                             return { label: item.module_task, value: item.task_id};
                   }))

                    },


                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        alert("here");

                        $(this).val(ui.item.module_task);
                        //$(this).val(ui.item.value);
                         //$("#txtAllowSearchID").val(ui.item.value);
                    }


                 /*  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                       //alert("error is " + errorThrown.toString());
                      //  alert("error is " + textStatus);
                       //  alert("json reponse is " +jqXHR.responseJSON );
                       // alert("json reponse is " +jqXHR.responseJSON );

                   }*/
                  });

              }
         });
      });

    $(document).on('autocompleteselect', '.autocomplete', function( event, ui ) {
               // alert("selected " + ui.item.value);
                var selectedTask = ui.item.value;
                lookUpDMCodeRea(selectedTask);
     });
  });

 });
})( jQuery );
```

and my json looks like this

```
  my json is like this
  var data =[
                            {
                                "task_id": "1539",
                                "module_task": "810-01"
                            },
                            {
                                "task_id": "1540",
                                "module_task": "810-02"
                            },
                            {
                                "task_id": "1541",
                                "module_task": "810-04"
                            },
                            {
                                "task_id": "13175",
                                "module_task": "810-04"
                            }
                     ]
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that the source should be the server code url where you get the json , and this is working for me , with php

```
 jQuery( this ).autocomplete({
  source: "<?php echo site_url("search_users.php"); ?>",
  minLength: 1,
  select: function( event, ui ) {

    //do something when a item is selected
    console.log(ui.item.id);


  }
}).data( "uiAutocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return jQuery( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append(
                    "<a style='cursor:pointer;'>"+
                    "<table>" +
                     "<tr>" +
                      "<td width='30'>" +
                        "<img src= '"+item.img+"' width='20' height='25' /> " +
                      "</td>" +
                      "<td>" +
                        item.label + 
                      "</td>" +
                     "</tr>" + 
                    "</table>"+
                    "</a>"
                    ) 
            .appendTo( ul );
};
```

and my json is :

```
                [
                        {
                            "label": "Juan Perez",
                            "value": "Juan Perez",
                            "id": 25,
                            "img": "http://localhost/admin/resources/as45265f."
                        },
                        {
                             "label": "Juan Perez",
                            "value": "Juan Perez",
                            "id": 25,
                            "img": "http://localhost/admin/resources/as45265f.jpg"
                        },
                        {
                             "label": "Juan Perez",
                            "value": "Juan Perez",
                            "id": 25,
                            "img": "http://localhost/admin/resources/as45265f.jpg"
                        },
                        {
                             "label": "Juan Perez",
                            "value": "Juan Perez",
                            "id": 25,
                            "img": "http://localhost/admin/resources/as45265f.jpg"
                        }
                 ]
```

Comment: no, my code is working fine until it returns the json object from ajax call, after I got json in the format I shown above, the response is not able to set in the textbox

Comment: can somebody help me with the solution or any alternative solution